# What's the meaning of color of rhombus in keyframe?

Tags: timeline

[image]

After I make frames as keyframe I found yellow colored rhombuses at keyframes in timeline editor. I clicked one of them out of curiosity and then the others turn to white. What's the meaning of the color ('yellow' and 'white')of rhombuses respectively in timeline editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yellow means active (selected). White is inactive.
While a keyframe is selected, you can move, scale and do whatever to the keyframe. You can also select multiple keyframes by holding shift.